# Convert typings defined with commonjs into typings without a module system

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm in process of migrating from VS 2013 + TS 1.8 into VS 2017 + TS 2.5

As part of this effort, it seems that I must update typings for react, etc.

Unfortunately, new typings are using commonjs :

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-dom

old typings didn't use any module system.

Is there a way to convert commonjs d.ts into "no modules" d.ts?

Answer (score 0):

The typings for react have `export as namespace React`, which is special -
 it allows you to just use the global variable `React`, if your code doesn't use any module system.

So, for example, this code compiles (and type checks) just fine with latest `typescript@2.7.2`, `@types/react@16.0.38` and `@types/react-dom@16.0.4`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here's more information about the special `export as namespace`  feature: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-umd-module-definitions